# Will search engines react to querystring ids as different pages?

Tags: seo, url, query-string

I've implemented my website to be like

```
domain/objects?id=xxx
```

like

```
domain/objects?id=bikeId
```

What I am worrying is the way that search engines will react to it.

I've already implemented the meta tags so each item will have it's own name printed into the **title** and **meta tags** but will they show it as different pages?

Is it suggested to implement a custom routing so instead I have the id in the url?

```
domain/objects/xxx
```

like

```
domain/objects/bikeId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but will they show it as different pages?

Yes, they are different URLs, therefore (unless otherwise stated) they will be seen and indexed as different *pages* in the SERPs.

If you wanted search engines to see these as the same URL then you would need to explicitly declare the *canonical* URL in the HTML and/or explicitly instruct Google to ignore the URL parameter in Google Search Console.

> Is it suggested to implement a custom routing...

You do not need to do that for *search engines*. That URL structure is primarily to benefit *users*, not search engines.

Answer (score 1):

Read Google's article about duplicate URLs and duplicate pages:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Also you can specify in Google Search Console which query params should be ignored.

If you cannot do both of it you can also exclude duplicate pages using robots.txt but I wouldn't recommend it

```
Disallow: /*?*id=
```

Comment: Although, in the OPs case, these would seem to be unique pages and it is desirable to get both URLs indexed.